# Is it possible to set a Metaclass globally so it applies to all classes created by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, metaclass

I get that a metaclass can be substituted for type and define how a newly created class behaves.

ex:

```
class NoMixedCase(type):
   def __new__(cls,clsname,base,clsdict):
       for name in clsdict:
          if name.lower() != name:
              raise TypeError("Bad name.Don't mix case!")
       return super().__new__(cls,clsname,base,clsdict)

class Root(metaclass=NoMixedCase):
    pass

class B(Root):
    def Foo(self): #type error
        pass
```

However, is there a way of setting NoMixedCase globally, so anytime a new class is created it's behavior is defined by NoMixedCase by default, without havining to inherit from Root?

So if you did...

```
Class B:  
    def Foo(self):
        pass
```

...it would still check case on method names.

Comment: `import this`: *Explicit is better than implicit.* What's the problem with specifying `metaclass=...`?

Comment: This is the kind of problem that should be approached by a linter program, maybe with a custom plug-in, and verified for at git commit time, with commit hooks.

Comment: In the future, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions. Use a version specific tag at your discretion.

Comment: Even if this were possible, it would break things all over the place in the standard library and in 3rd party libraries you depend on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your question, no, it it is not ordinarily - and possibly not even some extra-ordinary thng that will work for this - a lot of CPythons inner things are tied to the  `type` class, and hardcoded to it.

What is possible of trying, without crashing the interpretrer right away, would be to write a wrapper for `type.__new__` and use ctypes to replace it directly in `type.__new__` slot. (Ordinary assignment won't do it). You'd probably still crash things.

So, in real life, if you decide not to go via a linter program with a plug-in and commit hooks as I suggested in the comment above, the way to go is to have a Base class that uses your metaclass, and get everyone in your project to inherit from that Base.